# In QFT, can Field Operators at different points in Space-time always be expressed as unitary Transformation of each other?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity

Given an operator valued field $\Phi(x)$, and two points in spacetime, $x$ and $y$, can I always write down something like:

$$
\Phi(y) = U_{x,y}^{-1} \Phi(x) U_{x,y}
$$
With $U_{x,y}$ being an unitary Operator?

Comment: Yes, if the field theory is translationally invariant.

Comment: x-y interval timelike?

Comment: x-y is a spacelike interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you call a QFT. If it is an object satisfying the *definition* commonly known as the set of Wightman Axioms then the property is built into it, i.e., it follows from [Axiom W2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms#W2_.28transformation_law_of_the_field.29) together with the trivial transitivity of the action of the Poincaré group on spacetime.